# expl3 property list values as `clist` vs token lists

Tags: expl3

I have a (potentially) long property list, which `values`, at the moment, are just token lists. Now, I want to implement that some of the keys may have multiple values. I will store these multiple values in `clists`.

So, for each key I have to test if the value is a `clist` or just a token list. 
The case where the key may have just only one value can be seen as a special case of the `clist`, where just only one value can be inserted in the list.

I ask for advice, which approach will be easier to program:

1. `values` that can be either token lists or `clist`s? or
2. `values` that all are `clist`s, but some of them can only have one element?

(`key`, `value`) pairs will be set usually just once, and the `value` will be retrieved a few times (some of them several times, but I don't spect more than five times). I don't foresee a big difference in running time for both approaches. I an not sure if memory efficiency will be an issue with the "all `clist` approach."

**EDIT**

`egreg's` answwr is great (as usual). But I did not explain the problem at full. At the time to set the (`key`, `value`) pair for the first time, I don't have all the elements of list (if it is a list). So, I would have to:

1. Retrieve the `value`,
2. Check if it a list,
3. Insert the new value in the list

several times until the list type `keys` are filled. If I define all the values as `clists`. I can skip step number 2.  But them, when retrieved I guess I have to check if the `key` is a list or not.

The question boils down to the point if skipping step 2 make programming easier or not.

(After a deeper thought, it probably is equally easy/complicated because it is just moving the harder part to the setting or the retrieving of the `values`)

Comment: I solved a similar problem for myself using a second property list, storing datatypes of entries (though in my case there are also integers, dimensions, etc. possible).

Comment: @Skillmon I will create for sure a second  `prop` with will contain for each `key` that is should contain a list `true`. But my question is if it is easier to program the retrieve of `values` if all are lists.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the retrieved values and what should be in the token lists. The retrieval of values shouldn't be that hard either way. `\NewDocumentCommand\PrintKey{m}{ \prop_get:NnN \l_TeXtnik_key_types_prop { #1 } \l_TeXtnik_tmp_tl \exp_args:NV \tl_if_eq:nnTF \l_TeXtnik_tmp_tl { clist } { \TeXtnik_get_clist:n { #1 } } { \TeXtnik_get_tl:n { #1 } } }` and you're done. You could as well write above expandable (but slower) with `\prop_item:Nn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\prop_put:Nnn` is agnostic about the data you store in the sense that it does no interpretation to it; it's much like `\tl_set:Nn` in this respect, so in a sense a property list (*plist*) is a collection of token lists (*tl*) indexed by name.

Can this be a collection of *clists*? Yes, why not?

You can store the value as usual

```
\prop_put:Nnn \l_textnik_test_prop { a } { 1,2,3,4 }
```

and then retrieve it by assigning it to a *tl* variable:

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \textnik_prop_get_clist:NnN
 {
  \prop_get:NnN #1 {#2} \l__textnik_prop_get_clist_tl
  \clist_set:NV #3 \l__textnik_prop_get_clist_tl
 }
```

so that

```
\textnik_prop_get_clist:NnN \l_textnik_test_prop { a } \l_textnik_test_clist
```

will do the same as

```
\clist_set:Nn \l_textnik_test_clist { 1,2,3,4 }
```

If you want to extract the value as a *tl*, use `\clist_get:NnN`.

---

Here's a different implementation: each property refers to a `clist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Define a new data type pcl, only local settings.
% Add variants as needed and support for global setting.
\cs_new_eq:NN \textnik_pcl_new:N \prop_new:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \textnik_pcl_clear_new:N \prop_clear_new:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \textnik_pcl_clear:N \prop_clear:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \textnik_pcl_set_eq:NN \prop_set_eq:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \textnik_pcl_remove:NN \prop_remove:NN

% a global counter
\int_new:N \g__textnik_pcl_serial_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__textnik_pcl_check:Nn
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnF #1 { #2 }
   {% the property doesn't already exist
    \int_gincr:N \g__textnik_pcl_serial_int
    \prop_put:Nnx #1 { #2 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \g__textnik_pcl_serial_int } }
    \clist_new:c { l__textnik_pcl_ \int_to_arabic:n { \g__textnik_pcl_serial_int } _clist }
   }
 }

% adding items to a pcl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \textnik_pcl_put:Nnn
 {
  \__textnik_pcl_check:Nn #1 { #2 }
  \clist_set:cn { l__textnik_pcl_ \prop_item:Nn #1 { #2 } _clist } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \textnik_pcl_put_left:Nnn
 {
  \__textnik_pcl_check:Nn #1 { #2 }
  \clist_put_left:cn { l__textnik_pcl_ \prop_item:Nn #1 { #2 } _clist } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \textnik_pcl_put_right:Nnn
 {
  \__textnik_pcl_check:Nn #1 { #2 }
  \clist_put_right:cn { l__textnik_pcl_ \prop_item:Nn #1 { #2 } _clist } { #3 }
 }

% retrieving items from a pcl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \textnik_pcl_get:NnN
 {
  \clist_set_eq:Nc #3 { l__textnik_pcl_ \prop_item:Nn #1 { #2 } _clist }
 }

% showing a pcl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \textnik_pcl_show:N
 {
  \prop_map_function:NN #1 \__textnik_pcl_show:nn
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__textnik_pcl_show:nn
 {
  \clist_show:c { l__textnik_pcl_ #2 _clist }
 }

%%%% Test

\textnik_pcl_new:N \l_textnik_test_pcl
\textnik_pcl_put:Nnn \l_textnik_test_pcl { A } { A1,A2,A3 }
\textnik_pcl_put_right:Nnn \l_textnik_test_pcl { A } { A4,A5 }
\textnik_pcl_put_left:Nnn \l_textnik_test_pcl { A } { A0 }
\textnik_pcl_put:Nnn \l_textnik_test_pcl { B } { B1,B2,B3 }
\textnik_pcl_put_right:Nnn \l_textnik_test_pcl { B } { B4,B5 }
\textnik_pcl_put_left:Nnn \l_textnik_test_pcl { B } { B0 }

\clist_new:N \l_textnik_test_clist
\textnik_pcl_get:NnN \l_textnik_test_pcl {A} \l_textnik_test_clist
\clist_show:N \l_textnik_test_clist
\textnik_pcl_get:NnN \l_textnik_test_pcl {B} \l_textnik_test_clist
\clist_show:N \l_textnik_test_clist

%\textnik_pcl_show:N \l_textnik_test_pcl
```

A `pcl` is actually a `prop`, but the properties stored are just numbers that refer to an array of `clist`s.

The output is

```
The comma list \l_textnik_test_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {A0}
>  {A1}
>  {A2}
>  {A3}
>  {A4}
>  {A5}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.71 \clist_show:N \l_textnik_test_clist
                                        
? 
The comma list \l_textnik_test_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {B0}
>  {B1}
>  {B2}
>  {B3}
>  {B4}
>  {B5}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.73 \clist_show:N \l_textnik_test_clist
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited to clarify further my question.

Comment: @TeXtnik I added a different approach

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to study this carefully, :-) but I probably will use this apprach.

Comment: @TeXtnik Since adding an item to a `pcl` increases a global counter, the limit is 2³¹ such additions. I don't think it should bother you. `;-)`

Comment: No, It is no a problem!